# Erro com np.random.suffle, resultado None

Tags: python, numpy, dataset

Estou tentando misturar um dataset com 3 colunas para depois dividi-lo ao meio para uso de uma parte para treinamento e outra para teste de ML.
Estou usando o código:

```
Dataset = np.append (col1, col2, axis = 1)
Dataset = np.append (Dataset, d, axis = 1)
print(Dataset)
DataRand = np.random.shuffle(Dataset)
print(DataRand)
```

Meu resultado:

```
[[-0.04772459  0.07294899 -1.        ]
 [ 0.05032483  0.06084685 -1.        ]
 [ 0.04399538 -0.23125397 -1.        ]
 ...
 [ 1.00894279  0.89593335 -1.        ]
 [ 0.92998115  0.97773105 -1.        ]
 [ 0.80732527  1.00532736 -1.        ]]
None
```

Eu esperava que o dataset viesse com números diferentes, mas o resultado foi None...por que?
Como corrigir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função `np.random.shuffle` vai apenas embaralhar o seu dataset e não retorna nada, por isso que a sua variável `DataRand` é `None`. O que você pode fazer é uma cópia e depois embaralhar a copia, caso queira permanecer com a ordem inicial do seu dataset.

Ver esse simples exemplo:

```
import numpy as np

col = np.array([2,7,8,3,5])
col_copy = col.copy()
np.random.shuffle(col_copy)

print(col_copy)  # [5 8 2 3 7]
print(col)       # [2 7 8 3 5]
```

Comment: Eu criei uma variável chamada DataRand que recebe a outra variável embaralhada. Mantive a original e imaginei que DataRand receberia estes valores...Mas entendi!!!
Com ela não retorna nada, nela não gera dados pra DataRand... ok, muito perspicaz! :)